# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text' how can I solve it?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to practice web scraping by the book "Web Scraping with Python",,,however,I got an error "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'",,,can anyone tell me how can I solve it,very thanks,,,here is the code and error message,,,I use Python3 and MySql db and Mac os
[image]

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime
import random
import pymysql
import re

conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',unix_socket='/tmp/mysql.sock',user='root',passwd=None,db='mysql',charset='utf8')

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("USE scraping")

random.seed(datetime.datetime.now())

def store(title, content):
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO pages (title, content) VALUES (\"%s\",\"%s\")",    (title, content))
    cur.connection.commit()


def getLinks(articleUrl):
    html = urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org"+articleUrl)
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    title = bsObj.find("h1").find("span").get_text()
    content = bsObj.find("div", {"id":"mw-content- text"}).find("p").get_text()
    store(title, content)
    return bsObj.find("div",  {"id":"bodyContent"}).findAll("a",href=re.compile("^(/wiki/)((?!:).)*$"))

links = getLinks("/wiki/Kevin_Bacon")
try:
    while len(links) > 0:
        newArticle = links[random.randint(0, len(links)-1)].attrs["href"]
        print(newArticle)
        links = getLinks(newArticle)
finally:
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: The error message that you got means `bsObj.find("h1").find("span")` return `None`.

Comment: @shuttle87: Edited my comment.

Comment: Put a ```try/except``` around the statement to catch those anomalies if they are expected.

Comment: you mean this wiki may not be exist ?

Answer (score 2):

Because there's no `span` html tag inside the `h1` tag. If you want to get the text in `h1`, just remove that `.find('span')`:

```
title = bsObj.find("h1").get_text()
```

And there's a space in

```
content = bsObj.find("div", {"id":"mw-content- text"}).find("p").get_text()
                                              ^
```

Remove it:

```
content = bsObj.find("div", {"id":"mw-content-text"}).find("p").get_text()
```

Then your code maybe works fine.